# How can I get FLOAT data from user input (JTextfield)

Tags: java, floating-point

**How can I get FLOAT data from us

```
try{
    int num1,num2,num3,num4,sum;
    float div;
    DecimalFormat decft = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt_bin_balance.getText());
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(txt_issued_quantaty.getText());
    num3 = Integer.parseInt(txt_arrived_quantaty.getText());
    sum = (num1-num2)+num3;
    div = (float)sum;
    txt_final_bin_balance.setText(" " + String.valueOf(div)); 
} catch(Exception e){ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

but using this code and calculation it appear an error message like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrtCf.png)

I wont to do that

txt_final_bin_balance=(txt_bin_balance - txt_issued_quantaty )+ txt_arrived_quantaty

Result = (10-3.50)+6.15

Result = 12.65

1. get database value
2. get user input value and divide 1st value
3. calculation result add the second user input value with 2 decimal points
4. 1st result adding the second input value
5. final result shewing the jlable

Please help me to fix this issued
if anyone can gives the example to do this**(Examples need)**
Thanks

Comment: Ideally, you want to use`BigDecimal`s ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)) to do exact fixed-decimal arithmetic.  You can construct a `BigDecimal` from text: e.g., `new BigDecimal(txt_arrived_quantaty.getText())`.As a fallback, use `double` variables  instead of `int`s and parse with `Double.parseDouble`.

Comment: Why the all other variables int, but not div. I believe you should define sum as float.

Comment: I tried  Kevin Anderson code but still get an error! it will show in java.lang.UnsaportedOperationExeption:Not supported yet

Comment: `div` is already a floating-point variable. You already have it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking from how to get data and calculate and showing the jlable ,
      give me the example..please

Comment: please tell me how can i get floated values add to another floated or int/ double value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse "5.2" into int variable using `Integer.parseInt()` method, that is why you get a NumberFormatException. I am not exactly sure what you are asking for, but what I think you want is this:

```
try
{
    float num1,num2,num3,num4,sum;
    float div;
    DecimalFormat decft = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    num1 = Float.parseFloat(txt_bin_balance.getText());
    num2 = Float.parseFloat(txt_issued_quantaty.getText());
    num3 = Float.parseFloat(txt_arrived_quantaty.getText());
    sum = (num1-num2)+num3;
    div = (float)sum; //sum is alredy float so you dont need this one anymore
    txt_final_bin_balance.setText(" " + String.valueOf(div));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much its fixed my issued